# Swiping gestures - Android

Tags: java, android, swipe, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

I am trying to handle swipes from the user's finger.  I followed the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures).  From that example I came up with the following code:

```
public class GameScreen extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    TextView tv;

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getBaseContext(), new GestureListener());

    public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }
    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }
    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }
    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gamescreen);

        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);

        tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener() {     // ERROR:  "The method setOnTouchListener(View.onTouchListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnSwipeTouchListener(){})
            public void onSwipeTop() {
                Toast.makeText(GameScreen.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                Toast.makeText(GameScreen.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                Toast.makeText(GameScreen.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onSwipeBottom() {
                Toast.makeText(GameScreen.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Please notice near the bottom of the code in the `onCreate()` method where I have commented in the error message.  I am trying to just get this code working so that it displays `Toasts` notifying me that the swiping gestures are working.

My question is, what am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: where you have created OnSwipeTouchListener class?

Comment: Everything you see here is my entire project so far.  I just started this by using the link above.  Is the OnSwipeTouchListener class something already existing or do I need to write that from scratch?

Comment: in link example OnSwipeTouchListener class is separate java class and after then they are passing to setOnTouchListener method. so try in same way as in example

Comment: @matt you need to declare an interface namely `OnSwipeTouchListener` in your package then you can override its functionality in your `onCreate()`

Comment: Been busy and haven't had time to attempt the suggestions.  I will update here when I get a chance.

Comment: Thank you all!  Making the `OnSwipeTouchListener` a class worked!